# How to search and manipulate data on jTable in java in netbeans

Tags: java, excel, swing, loops, netbeans-8

[i need help in java programming in netbeans.
suppose i have 2 jTable. the first table contains the imported data from the excel file (I do not use data in the database). And the second table serves to display data calculation results from the first table earlier.
questions asked are:

1. how to find the value of MAXIMUM and MINIMUM in each column, starting from column two, third and so on. and displayed eg in jTextfiield?
2. how, for example I have a sum formula, which serves to add all the values ​​in row 1 in columns 2,3,4, and so on in the first table. then the formula will be reused on the second line, then and so on for each row in the first table, according to the number of rows in the first table. such as in excel, (which when we have a certain formula we live just copy and drag the cursor down, then automatically all the values ​​on all rows summed)?
3. lastly how to display all the data in the first table along with the result of the sum in each line before the previous formula, in the second jTable?

please help, just info I use java in netbeans. and for the image of his table I attach also along with this post. thanks.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ41q.png)

Comment: I think you need to start learn programming. Try to play with two-dimentional arrays to learn how to find max/min in a column/row and so on.

Comment: 1) *"lastly how to.."* Firstly, each question should have ***one*** clear and specific question. Your question has three, and it is not entirely clear to me in some case what you expect the output to be, or where it should appear. This part might be helped if you create an image of sample inputs in excel (or another spreadsheet), then show the expected outputs in **bold** to demonstrate the relationship between them. 2) Each question/thread on SO should include a [mcve] showing how the data looks in code, and include any attempt you made to implement the requirement.